# asp:RequiredFieldValidator with telerik RadDatePicker

Tags: asp.net, telerik

> I using the asp:RequiredFieldValidator with telerik:RadDatePicker but the validation. style not appear ,this is my code:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker RenderMode="Lightweight" EnableTyping="false" ID="RDPAddPremisesAndFixedListDate" runat="server">
                    <DateInput
                        DateFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
                        DisplayDateFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
                        CssClass="general-profile-Date">
                    </DateInput>
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvPremisesAndFixedListDate" ControlToValidate="RDPAddPremisesAndFixedListDate"
                    ErrorMessage="This Field is Empty" ValidationGroup="AddPremises" CssClass="error-msg" />
```

This screenshot for my fields, all validation style appear except the (telerik:RadDatePicker), what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just added (extra-id="_dateInput_wrapper") in RequiredFieldValidator :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).